# Trying to trace a security issue. Can someone expain how ruby gem versioning works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, version

Say you have a Rails application that uses ActiveRecord 4.2.5 and an included gem that uses an earlier version, say 3.2.14. Do both versions get loaded and used independently (I'm guessing yes)? Is there any way I can make this gem use a newer version? The gem in question has this entry in my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    .
    .
    .
    fuzzily (0.3.3)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.17)
```

Comment: What does your `Gemfile.lock` list in terms of dependencies? If the included gem specifies 3.2.14 exactly in its Gemfile, then I don't think there's much you can do - other than changing it and re-bundling...

Comment: @Brian I updated my question. The gem (fuzzily) appears to require anything above 2.3.17. Can I depend on the Gemfile.lock to know what gem versions my app is using? If it requires anything after 2.3.17 does this mean that Fuzzily will use the ArctiveRecord that the rest of my app is using (4.2.5)?

Comment: There should be another entry in your Gemfile.lock that says specifically what version of activerecord is in use. Since fuzzily is specifying anything greater than 2.3.17, it should use whatever the rest of the app is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails will not use two versions of the gem, it will default the usage of the gem to the latest version.
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/751

You can always specify which version of Active Record you want your gem to use, provided that Active Record version is compatible with your gem. You can download the repositories of both versions of said gem in your local file. Then provide local paths pointing to both the gems separately and add these gems (with the paths) in your gem file.

eg.

> gem 'grpc', :path => '/Users/admin/repository/grpc' .
>   gem 'grpc', :path => '/Users/admin/grpc'